# Why are arrow functions in a for loop faster than global functions?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, loops, arrow-functions

I wanted to test whether using an arrow function in a for loop is much slower than using a global function. To me surprise, in all tested browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox) the arrow function in a for loop was faster than the global function by an order of 5-10x.

I have created a [jsperf here](https://jsperf.com/arrow-function-in-for-loop).

Here's the initial loop:

```
  for(let i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
     (i) => sum += i;
     (sum, i) => sum += i;
  }
```

Here's what I thought should be faster:

```
   for(let i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
      add(i);
      addTwo(sum, i);
   }
```

Where the add functions are just global functions:

```
  function add(i) {
     return sum += i;
  }
  function addTwo(sum, i) {
     return sum += i;
  }
```

Shouldn't re-using the global functions be faster than creating an arrow function at each iteration?

**LE:**
The test code was wrong, I was not actually calling the arrow functions, now I updated it to this:

```
   for(let i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
      ((i) => sum += arr[i])();
      ((sum, i) => sum += arr[i])();
   }
```

Seems now that the global function method is, as expected, faster now (x2 on chrome, x300 on Firefox, x20 on Edge).

Comment: Your code with the arrow functions doesn't actually *call* the functions, so basically the loop does nothing at all.

Comment: @Pointy Lol, oops...

Comment: I have updated the JSPerf, it works as expected now, global functions are 2x faster. :)

Comment: I have also voted to close my own question,  thanks @Pointy for Pointying out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You dont create a "new" arrow function at each iteration. The function is set up once when js parses your script, it will only create a closure at each iteration. But as you dont call the function, the closure isnt needed at all and your for loop does nothing, therefore its fast.